# One Kubernetes dashboard for multiple clusters

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

Is it possible to use **one** Kubernetes Web UI (Dashboard) for several independent clusters, with a simple switch between them?
Using a proxy to the dashboard of each cluster is not appropriate, because not all clusters have external access.

> Example of an infrastructure:

```
   |:80 |:443
 -------------       -------------       -------------
 | Cluster A |       | Cluster B |       | Cluster N |
 -------------       -------------       -------------
       |                   |                   |
------ management, logging, ci-cd, etc. Environment --------
| Gitlab | Redmine | K8s Dashboard | ELK | ... | ... | ... |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Kubernetes Dashboard doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Furthermore, even if it could, kubernetes dashboard requires access to the API server of the cluster in the same way `kubectl proxy` does, so if proxy will not work, neither would dashboard.

Comment: I meant directly proxy for Web UI in clusters. [Kubernetes API server](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Accessing-Dashboard---1.7.X-and-above#api-server) I will use for centralized management of services. But this does not help because it means running dashboard in all clusters.

Comment: dashboard is really lightweight so there is really no harm running it on each cluster